# Implementing Static Methods common to multiple Classes

Tags: c#, sql, static-methods

I have a WinForms app written in C# which has a lot of custom Classes.
Many of those Clases share similar Properties and Methods, and I have been able to cut down on the Coding by using Inheritance.
However, my Classes also have a lot of similar Static Methods (often the only thing that differs from one implementation to another between Classes is the reference to the Class itself.  A very dumbed down example of this might be -

```
public class MyClass1()
{
    public string IdentifyYourself()
    {
        return "This is the IdentifyYourself method in " + typeof(MyClass1).Name;
    }
}

public class MyClass2()
{
    public string IdentifyYourself()
    {
        return "This is the IdentifyYourself method in " + typeof(MyClass2).Name;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to generalize the code in the IdentifyYourself() method so that there is no need to keep restating the Class in each implementation?

If these were not Static Methods then I could do something like

```
this.GetType().Name;
```

But of course the 'this' keyword is unavailable in a Static Method.

You may be wondering why these need to be Static methods.  However the above example is not my actual code but a simplified version of the issue I am having.  An actual example from my code (but still one of the shorter examples) is as follows -

```
public static DataTable List(bool active = true)
    {
        try
        {
            string table = typeof(MyClass).Name;
            string sqlText = "SELECT * FROM [" + table + "] WHERE Active = @Active;";
            SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlText);
            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", active);
            DataTable results = Express.GetTable(sqlCom);
            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

The Code for the List() implementation differs from one Class to the next only in the first line

```
string table = typeof(MyClass).Name;
```

I'm thinking that if I could generalize this in some way, I could re-factor the code as follows -

```
public static DataTable List(bool active = true)
        {
            try
            {
                string nameOfClass = //...some generalized way of obtained the Name of the class...//
                return UtilityClass.List(nameOfClass);
            }
            ...
        }
```

It is then a straight copy and paste of just a couple of lines of code each time I want to implement this in a new class and all the more detailed code can be placed in a Utility Class.  The advantage of this isn't just avoiding having to type the name of each Class in each implementation, but also, if the details of the SQL operations need to change, it only has to be changed in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic way to do that would be generics:

```
public static DataTable List<T>(bool active = true)
{
    try
    {
        string table = typeof(T).Name;
        // ...
    } ....
```

and

```
var table = YourStaticClass.List<MyClass1>();
```

Frankly, however, I would also recommend making it return `List<T>` rather than `DataTable`. That depends a bit on what `Express` is, however (but: "dapper" would be trivial to use to do the query into a `List<T>`)

Comment: Is applying generics good in this situation, since the code is not utilizing anything which generic provides. We just need the class name... that's it!

Comment: @VimalCK a: that is just one example, b: what we really need is the `Type` instance, and generics can be a convenient and appropriate way to do that - from the `Type` we have access to the attributes, properties, etc, c: note my recommendation to return `List<T>` instead of `DataTable`. All in all, I'm pretty happy with a generics-based solution here. But yes, `Type` could also be a parameter.